# Text alignment on header images

Tags: website-design, user-research

I was wondering if there is any statistics/research done on Text overlaying Hero, or header images. If right aligned and left aligned is better (or if it doesn't make a difference).

Struggling to find anything -

Thoughts?

Comment: What is a hero image?

Comment: After using Google, I found out that a *hero image* is a super imposed (=large) image on the landing (home) page.

Comment: you're better off A/B testing on your own site than blinding following what worked for someone else.

Comment: That question is too vague. There is general implications to aligning text one way or another, but I doubt this will be a fruitful topic without something more concrete to go on.

Answer (score 1):

It depend what you are trying to achieve... Left hand side if you  want the user to concentrate on the text 1st, but if you want the user to enjoy the image and then move on to text and CTA it should be right aligned.
take a look at these two articles they will explain the way the user reads/scans the pages 
[ux movement](http://uxmovement.com/buttons/why-users-click-right-call-to-actions-more-than-left-ones/) and [useit.com](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/reading_pattern.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think JPizzle is asking whether or not the text *within* the hero aligned left or right.

My answer (to that) is it depends on what its overlaying. Does the image have a strong right or left focus? You may want to left align text that has a strong left side focus, but right align text with a strong right side focus.

Also consider the amount of text used.